# C# System.Collections.Generic.Icollection<> does not contain definition for RemoveAll

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, reference

This is part of some code that works perfectly fine on my coworker's machine, but when I try to compile the solution I get the error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAll' and no extension method 'RemoveAll' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I cross-checked our references, and they seem to match. I have a reference to System.Linq and EntityFramework. I tried cleaning and recompiling, but this error still sticks.

```
public void CleanClearinghouse()
{
    this.ClearinghousePartners.RemoveAll(
        x =>
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ClearingHouseName) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.TradingPartnerName) && !x.StartDate.HasValue);
}
```

I have a feeling I am missing an assembly reference or something similar. 
I would appreciate any tips on where to look for a solution, but no suggestions for changing the code.

Comment: RemoveAll does not exist on ICollection<T>. It is a method on lists.

Comment: If you use "Go to definition" on your co-worker's machine, what does it find?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram It's also an extension method on `ICollection<T>` in some assemblies. Without more info, we can't tell which is supposed to be the case here.

Comment: What type is `ClearinghousePartners`? Because RemoveAll is a method on `List<T>`, not `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: It goes to @hvd
// Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1
// Assembly: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan ClearninghousePartners is Icollection type

Comment: @AidaM Okay, then it's what Anthony Pegram guessed already: your `ClearinghousePartners` doesn't have the same type it has on your co-worker's machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that `ICollection<T>` does not contain a method called RemoveAll. 
The class that *does* have RemoveAll is `List<T>`, which is probably the actual, concrete type of your variable.

However, if your property is of type ICollection, the compiler has no way of knowing that it's actually a List.

Say, something like this:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public ICollection<string> ClearinghousePartners {get;set;}
    public MyClass() 
    {
        ClearingHousePartners = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Won't compile, because the `List<string>` is exposed as an `ICollection<string>`.

One way of fixing it is to change the property definition to be `List<T>` instead of `ICollection`.

Comment: It was the issue with how ClearinghousePartners was autogenerated (as Icollection) and the fact it was declared as List in the constructor that was mismatched. Once declaration and assignment were matching the error disappeared. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since `ICollection` doesn't have `RemoveAll`, if you want to keep the code you already have, one option is to implement the `RemoveAll` yourself, like this:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, Predicate<T> match) 
    where T : ClearinghousePartners
{
    if (match == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("match");

    collection.Where(entity => 
        match(entity)).ToList().ForEach(entity => collection.Remove(entity));
}
```

Note: This is an extension method and so needs to be put into a static class.